# pick Calender with dynamic id how to write code for static

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am selecting date from calendar in two places in the same page,But the calendar id is dynamic and not able to pick the static value suggestion please how to use in selenium webdriver

```
<p-calendar id="effectiveFromDate" class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" inputstyleclass="form-control" name="effectiveFromDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required="">
<!--template bindings={}-->
<span class="ui-calendar">
<input id="dp1479794880786" class="form-control hasDatepicker ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" readonly="" type="text"/>
<!--template bindings={}-->
</span>


<p-calendar id="effectiveToDate" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" inputstyleclass="form-control" name="effectiveToDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
<!--template bindings={}-->
<span class="ui-calendar">
<input id="dp1479794880787" class="form-control hasDatepicker ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" readonly="" type="text"/>
<!--template bindings={}-->
</span>
```

I am using the below code but not able to use in the same page

```
driver.findElement(By.className("ui-calendar")).click();
```

```html
<p-accordiontab id="invOverviewTab" header="Invoice Overview" styleclass="margin-b-10">
<div class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-active">
<div class="ui-accordion-content-wrapper" style="">
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-widget-content">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-t-10 margin-b-10">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="item form-group">
<div class="item form-group invoice-config marginB">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="effectiveFromDate">
<p-calendar id="effectiveFromDate" class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" inputstyleclass="form-control" name="effectiveFromDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required="">
<!--template bindings={}-->
<span class="ui-calendar">
<input id="dp1479805294453" class="form-control hasDatepicker ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" readonly="" type="text"/>
<!--template bindings={}-->
</span>
<!--template bindings={}-->
</p-calendar>
<p class="text-danger" hidden="">Effective From Date is required</p>
</div>
<!--template bindings={}-->
<div class="form-group">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-t-10 margin-b-10">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group text-right">
</div>
</div>
</p-accordiontab>
```

```html
<p-accordiontab id="invOverviewTab" header="Invoice Overview" styleclass="margin-b-10">
<div class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-active">
<div class="ui-accordion-content-wrapper" style="">
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-widget-content">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-t-10 margin-b-10">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="item form-group">
<div class="item form-group invoice-config marginB">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="effectiveFromDate">
<p-calendar id="effectiveFromDate" class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" inputstyleclass="form-control" name="effectiveFromDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required="">
<!--template bindings={}-->
<span class="ui-calendar">
<input id="dp1479805294453" class="form-control hasDatepicker ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" readonly="" type="text"/>
<!--template bindings={}-->
</span>
<!--template bindings={}-->
</p-calendar>
<p class="text-danger" hidden="">Effective From Date is required</p>
</div>
<!--template bindings={}-->
<div class="form-group">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-t-10 margin-b-10">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group text-right">
</div>
</div>
</p-accordiontab>
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  <p-accordion id="accMenu" class="custom-theme-accordion">
<div class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset">
<p-accordiontab id="billClientTab" header="Bill To Client Information">
<div class="row">
<p-accordiontab id="invOverviewTab" header="Invoice Overview" styleclass="margin-b-10">
<div class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-active">
<div class="ui-accordion-content-wrapper" style="">
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-widget-content">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-t-10 margin-b-10">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="item form-group">
<div class="item form-group invoice-config marginB">
<div class="form-group">
<!--template bindings={}-->
<div class="form-group">
<label for="effectiveToDate">Effective To Date</label>
<p-calendar id="effectiveToDate" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" inputstyleclass="form-control" name="effectiveToDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
<!--template bindings={}-->
<span class="ui-calendar">
<input id="dp1479805294454" class="form-control hasDatepicker ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" readonly="" type="text"/>
<!--template bindings={}-->
</span>
<!--template bindings={}-->
</p-calendar>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-t-10 margin-b-10">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group text-right">
</div>
</div>
</p-accordiontab>
```

Comment: Where does the "p" element ends? the input is inside the "p" ? because you need to get the selector based on that element.

Comment: Please find the attched code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `span` tag is child element of `p-calender` tag:

If you want to click `effectiveFromDate` then use the following XPATH:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='effectiveFromDate']/span")).click();
```

If you want to click on `effectveToDate`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='effectiveToDate']/span")).click();
```

---

Instead of clicking the calender, you can directly enter the Date in `FromDate` (MM/DD/YYYY format) by identifying input tag as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='effectiveFromDate']/span/input")).sendKeys("01/01/1990");
```

Similarly for `To Date`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='effectiveToDate']/span/input")).sendKeys("02/01/1990");
```

Comment: what is the exception? can you share the HTML code? add to the question, from image it is not clear whether it is a child of the element

Comment: edited xpath. try again. removed "p-calendar" and keep "*"